# Book for real projective space

Tags: projective-geometry

I need a book that analytically studies the real projective space, one that is very clear and has examples. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

How about *Perspectives on Projective Geometry* by Jürgen Richter-Gebert?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.